# Unknown startup program

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just found out this strange startup program of which I cannot get any details. How to eliminate it? Not virus, I scan with Avast and MalwareBytes often.

[image]

Comment: Check and post the whole path to the executable file.

Comment: If i press right click on it, open file and properties are greyed out, I can only search it online

Comment: @w32sh thx, I also used the program mentioned bellow and it points to a folder of bitdefender which I uninstalled last week C:\Program Files\Common Files\Bitdefender\SetupInformation\{09FE2C2E-BB0D-4848-A706-AA244FA25FEA}\setuplauncher.exe

Comment: Something left behind after BitDefender uninstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ["Sysinternals Autoruns"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) tool to get the details of the program and also to remove/disable its autostart location.

Comment: I guess I found it,what do I do next?

Comment: Just delete it in "Autoruns".

Comment: thx pops you the boss

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the column header (Name, Publisher, Status) and enable `Command-line` option. This shows the full path for that program.

Go to the corresponding folder location, right-click on the executable and click Properties. That may provide additional information such as the Product Name, Date etc.

Comment: folder is deleted, how do i make it vanish from the startup menu?

Comment: You should be able to clear the entry using Autoruns, as user "Resistor Resisting Rodriguez" posted above. Or by deleting the corresponding value from the Registry "Run" or "RunOnce" keys. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396